Masstransit saga state machine event not triggering after response received from kafka topic
I am orchestrating data flow using masstransit saga state machine/kafa. I am facing one strange issue where state machine event not triggering upon receiving response from kafka topic.
Saga config
private static void RiderConfiguration(IRiderRegistrationConfigurator config, Configuration configuration)
{
    config.AddInMemoryInboxOutbox();

    IMongoDatabase db = AddMongoSagaDatabase(configuration.MongoConfiguration);

    config.AddSagaStateMachine<PipelineStateMachine, PipelineRunState>()
        .MongoDbRepository(db, cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DatabaseName = configuration.MongoConfiguration.DatabaseName;
        });    
}

Endpoint config
private static IKafkaFactoryConfigurator AddConsumerToBuilder<TMessage>(
        IKafkaFactoryConfigurator configurator,
        IRiderRegistrationContext context,
        string topicName,
        string groupId,
        Configuration configuration)
        where TMessage : class
    {
        configurator.TopicEndpoint<string, TMessage>(
            topicName,
            new ConsumerConfig() { GroupId = groupId, AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest },
            endpointConfig =>
            {
                endpointConfig.SetValueDeserializer(new JsonDeserializer<TMessage>());

                endpointConfig.UseMessageRetry(r =>
                {
                    r.Immediate(configuration.KafkaConfiguration.RetryCount);
                    r.Handle<MongoDbConcurrencyException>();
                });
                endpointConfig.UseInMemoryOutbox(context);

                endpointConfig.ConfigureSaga<PipelineRunState>(context);
            });
        return configurator;
    }

Producer config
 private static void AddProducerToBuilder<TMessage>(this IRiderRegistrationConfigurator config, string topicName)
     where TMessage : class
 {
     config.AddProducer<string, TMessage>(
         topicName,
         (ctx, cfg) =>
         {
             cfg.BatchNumMessages = 1;
             cfg.Linger = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
             cfg.SetValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<TMessage>());
         });
 }

Events
InstanceState(config => config.CurrentState);

Initially(
    When(FundamentalDataReceived)
        .Then(context => TransitionToState(context, Initializing))
        .Activity(a => a.OfType<InitializationActivity>()));

OnUnhandledEvent(async e => await e.Ignore());

DuringAny(
    When(ProducerValidationResult)
        .IfElse(
            ctx => ctx.Message.IsSuccess,
            successBinder => successBinder
                .Then(ctx => LogContext.Debug?.Log("[{CorrelationId}]ProducerValidation.Result.Success", ctx.CorrelationId))
                .Then(ctx => TransitionToState(ctx, Initialized))
                .Activity(a => a.OfInstanceType<RequestMovementActivity>()),
            failedBinder => failedBinder
                .Then(ctx => LogContext.Debug?.Log("[{CorrelationId}]ProducerValidation.Result.Fail", ctx.CorrelationId))
                .Then(ctx => TransitionToState(ctx, ProducerValidationFailed))
                .Activity(a => a.OfInstanceType<RequestQuarantineActivity>())));

When fundamental data received, I am producing a msg to kafka topic as part of InitializationActivity. The corresponding service process the message and sending ProducerValidationResult. This flow is working fine most of times but When(ProducerValidationResult) event is not firing once in a while after receiving the result
I enabled debug logging on dev environment and cross check the documentation/examples but no luck as of now. Much appreciated if someone who worked on masstransit saga using kafka throw some light into this issue.
Here is the log for one of messages where the ProducerValidationResult event did not trigger even after receiving result msg
State machine log



Timestamp
Message




2024-08-08 15:06:20.057
[41 msec] Published message with CorrelationId: "e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.118
SAGA:"Test.MyTest.Messaging.StateMachine.Saga.PipelineRunState":e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3 Created "Test.MyTest.Messaging.Messages.Events.IngestFundamental"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.118
SAGA:"Test.MyTest.Messaging.StateMachine.Saga.PipelineRunState":e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3 Added "Test.MyTest.Messaging.Messages.Events.IngestFundamental"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.118
[e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3]Transitioning to state: "Initializing (State)"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.118
[e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3]Requesting producer validation


2024-08-08 15:06:20.167
SEND loopback://localhost/kafka/test.validation.producer.request 01000000-eec8-261d-ed84-08dcb7b34730 "Test.MyTest.Messaging.Messages.Requests.ProducerValidationRequest"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.167
[49 msec] Published message with correlationId: e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3 into kafka topic: "test.validation.producer.request"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.227
RECEIVE loopback://localhost/kafka/test.validation.producer.result 01000000-1f32-a67a-c38e-08dcb7b34738 "Test.MyTest.Messaging.Messages.Events.ProducerValidationResult" "Test.MyTest.Messaging.StateMachine.Saga.PipelineRunState"(00:00:00.0018114)



Producer validation service log



Timestamp
Message




2024-08-08 15:06:20.167
Received message with correlationId: "e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3"


2024-08-08 15:06:20.217
[47 msec] Published message with correlationId: "e1fa4086-8fc1-4d1d-b4c1-8dab3a4bd0f3" into kafka topic: "test.validation.producer.result"




Stack Overflow is not a support channel for MassTransit. If you can reproduce the problem in a standalone repository on GitHub, create a discussion on GitHub with that repository. Otherwise, you'll need to go through support.

The issue is fixed when I pre create saga instance by setting InsertOnInitial to true
